# Android Camera Okay Icon Not showing

Tags: android

I am using the following code to launch the camera in my android App

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
   outputFileUri);
   startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

the problem is the first time i run the application i keep clicking the camera icon and it keeps taking pictures. it never shows the check mark until i click back and then launch again then it shows the check mark after taking a picture. what can be the problem?

I am running minSdkVersion 15.
[image]

Comment: There's nothing you can do about whatever your problem is.  The camera app is a separate application, other than the parameters you send to start it there's nothing you can do to control it.  ALso, don't expect any particular behavior from it, the camera app varies between OEMs, models, and Android versions.

Comment: You could add an interface for your camera that the Activity or fragment or viewmodel could listen when the taking of photo is done. To make it work you should disable the capture button while the camera hasn't called the done function in the interface implementation.